# What is valueattr in polymer?

Tags: html, polymer

Assalamualaikum and hello everyone. 
As I was reading through this page: https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/spa.html I came up with the following code snippet which isn't making that much sense to me.

```html
<core-menu valueattr="hash" selected="{{route}}">
  <template repeat="{{page in pages}}">
    <paper-item label="{{page.name}}" hash="{{page.hash}}">
      <a href="#{{page.hash}}"></a>
    </paper-item>
  </template>
</core-menu>

<core-animated-pages valueattr="hash" selected="{{route}}" transitions="slide-from-right">
  <template repeat="{{page in pages}}">
    <section hash="{{page.hash}}" layout vertical center-center>
      <div>{{page.name}}</div>
    </section>
  </template>
</core-animated-pages>
```

Here, the documentation says that:

> Notice that `<core-animated-pages>` and `<core-menu>` are linked by
>   binding their **selected** attributes together. Now, when a user clicks on
>   a nav item the view updates accordingly. The **valueattr="hash"** tells
>   both elements to use the hash attribute on each item as the selected
>   value.

I'm not getting this part. Is the value of `valueattr` being used as a key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember `<core-menu>` is using `<core-selector>` internally and `valueattr` is the attribute name used by `<core-selector>` to identify the selected item.

Comment: Then what does `selected="{{route}}"` do?

Comment: `<core-menu>` selects the `<paper-item>` whose `hash` attribute has the same value as the `route` field in the model.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I get it. `valueattr` actually specifies the **attribute** (of the child elements) to be used as its `selected` value.

Here, `selected="{{route}}"` is actually just binding a model to the two parent elements, so that they are updated automatically if any one of the parent element's `selected` value is changed (2-way data binding).

Hope that helps :)